# Tensors of arbitrary rank inside compiler

Tags: compile

I want to create a compiled function that executes operations with lists of tensors. It has two arguments, two lists of tensors, and takes the tensor products between tensors of both lists. Is it possible to create such a function with compile? Although all tensors in each list have the same rank, the rank from one list is not the same as the rank of tensors in another list and I won't have these ranks predefined, but they are all rectangular: dimensions = {d,d,d,...}, where d is the same number for tensors from both lists. I just need to know if the compiler can take lists of tensors with unspecified rank as input.

Comment: No, `Compile` cannot do it, and `LibraryLink` does not allow you to do it either: The Ranks are compile time constants. But you encode tensors just as vectors a along with the vector of integers that describe the dimensions. That is basically the internally used format for tensors. The only problem: `Compile`  and `LibraryLink` do not allow you to return more than one object at the time. But at least `LibraryLink` allows you to return by reference through `"Shared"` arguments.

Comment: Humm thank you, I think I may define a function to generate the compiled function in real time then. The operations are really simple, and it is a small set of them, so it shoudn't take much time.

Comment: Yeah, compile a bunch of them and memoize them. I often find myself doing things akin to `cf[rank_]:=cf[rank]=With[{rank=rank},Compile[{{x,_Real,rank},...]];`